# Replication with SQL Server 2008 Web edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

I need to use replication between my databases. But me hosting provides only Web Edition of SQL Server. In web edition replication is not supported. May be anyone have some suggestions? 
Thanks

Comment: As you say yourself, the SQL Server Web Edition does **not** support replication. So basically you could a) find yourself a new hoster that supports other editions of SQL Server so you can use replication, or b) you could write your own "replication"-like functionality in T-SQL or other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are savvy with programming then you can accomplish a very slim form of replication through code.  If not, you might be out of luck.

You can have DML triggers on your tables that you would normally have as *articles* for replication, and when the data changes log it to a table with the necessary information.  Then have a scheduled task that runs an application to push those changes to the logical *subscriber(s)*.  Just an idea, but it looks like you may have to get creative.